# More badly and most badly

Tags: meaning, adverbs, comparatives

According to [Collins English Usage](https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/bad#2),

> Badly has another different meaning. If you need or want something
>   badly, you need or want it **very much**: *I am badly in need of
>   advice; I want this job so badly; We badly need the money*.
>
> For this meaning of badly, don't use the comparative and superlative
>   forms ‘worse’ and ‘worst’. Instead you use the forms **more badly** and
>   **most badly**.

Is this distinction due to its meaning "*(very) **much***", which already uses *more/most* as its comparative/superlative forms?

Comment: It's mainly that worse/worst just don't sound right in this context.

Comment: Someone could be in *worse* need of advice.

Comment: Suppose [Jack Sprat and his wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Sprat) have had nothing to eat for days, so they're both badly in need of food. Obviously Jack himself is ***more / most badly*** in need (because he doesn't have so much body fat to sustain him during lean times), and we certainly wouldn't say he was ***worse in need***. But I'd be happy to say *Jack is the **worse / worst prepared** for food shortages*, as an alternative to ***most badly prepared***.

Comment: _ I want this job so badly; We badly need the money_ are also used as examples which use **more/most**

Comment: "Badly has *another* different meaning"? As opposed to the same different meaning? Oy. Usually this is a cut & paste error, where I pop two word choices into one spot, to compare -- then delete one, unless I drink and edit. Compared to this advice, I vote for "I need trustworthy advice, bad."

Comment: @YosefBaskin rather bad punctuation: _another, different meaning_

Comment: Actually, "badder than old King Kong" is more idiomatic.

Comment: 'Badly' is itself an intensifier here. Modifying it using 'more' or 'most' don't always sound natural; 'so badly') (as you indicate), 'very badly' and 'really badly' are more usual. 'Worse / worst' usually sound awful, though 'She's got it worse than Sue' ('fancies more strongly') used to be common in slang.

Answer (score -2):

Worse and worst are the comparative and superlative forms of the adjective bad not the adverb badly. If you want to say more bad, you should use worse, but now you're using badly. So you would need to use worsely. But worsely isn't a word. You can't say "I am worsely in need of money than before". So you have to use more badly.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worsely

Comment: It seems to me that "worse" can be the comparative form of "badly". For example, I sing worse than you do.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could. But badly inthis context means 'much', so you can't use worse. And worsely is very uncommon.

Comment: My dictionary has: "worse", adjective, comparative of "bad"; but also adverb, comparative of "badly".  (Oxford American Dictionary)

Comment: *Worse* is the standard comparative form of *badly*. You use it except for the cases discussed in the question.